# Weird mark/sign/punctuation in MS-Word. How to delete it?

Tags: ms-word

I know this might be trivial but I'm looking now for over 2 hours and I just can't find a solution for it.

I have a table in MS-Word with 2 columns. In both columns there is this weird punctuation which looks like a sun. It is a circle with 4 lines. (See Picture below).

What is it doing? This sign won't allow me to write anything after that even though, the sentence is midway. And if there is a sentence I want to delete the sign still remains afterwards in the empty row...

Does anyone know how to delete this mark?

[image: The image]

Comment: turn off the Formatting Marks https://kranjac.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/formatting-marks-in-word-2010-showhide/

Comment: Hi. I know that it is a formatting mark. I want to know how to delete that "rule" in specific rows. For example I can delete the paragraph mark easily pressing delete or backwards. But the one I showed you wont be deleted when I press it. Any other idea?

Comment: you can't delete it (you delete the cell or paragraph, not the marks). You can merge cells or use the eraser http://aimyaya.com/2011/12/how-to-easily-combine-microsoft-word-table-columns.html

Comment: Can you upload your file somewhere and give the link to it? Btw which version of MS-Word are you using?